# Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) [python, socket]

Tags: python-2.7, sockets

1. os - windows server 2012
2. python - 2.7.11
   this program is server-side code for receiving data on socket.
   but sometimes the error is thrown and I don't know where it can be.
   i attached the code-sample

   ```
   import sys, socket, datetime, threading
   import conf, work_with_DB, log
   import subprocess
   ```

   `class socket_server():
       def __init__(self, ip, port):
       self.ip = ip
       self.port = port

       #asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
       sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
       # write to log
       log.logging('time %s' % datetime.datetime.now(), self.port)
       #log.logging('create socket on -> %s' % conf.LOCAL_server_ip[0])
       log.logging('create socket on -> %s:%d' % (self.ip, self.port),     self.port)

       #print 'create socket on -> %s' % conf.LOCAL_server_ip[0]
       print 'create socket on -> %s:%d' % (self.ip, self.port)

       self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
       # write to log
       log.logging('bind to socket', self.port)
       print 'bind to socket'
       #sock.bind(conf.LOCAL_server_ip)
       self.sock.bind((self.ip, self.port))
       # write to log
       log.logging('listen socket...', self.port)
       print 'listen socket...'
       self.sock.listen(5)

   def run(self):
       self.conn, self.addr = self.sock.accept()
       # write to log
       #log.logging('accept connection from -> ip=%s' % addr[0])
       log.logging('accept connection from -> %s:%s...time =%s' % (self.ip, self.port, datetime.datetime.now()), self.port)

       #print 'accept connection from -> ip= %s, port= %s...time= %s' % (addr[0], addr[1], now_time)
       print 'accept connection from -> %s:%s...time =%s' % (self.ip, self.port, datetime.datetime.now())

        while True:
           # receiving TCP-data
           self.query_from_MES = self.conn.recv(10000).strip()

           if not len(self.query_from_MES) == 0:
               # log.logging('receive from -> ip =%s, port =%s...time =%s' % (addr[0], addr[1], now_time))
               log.logging('receive from -> %s:%s...time =%s' % (self.ip, self.port, datetime.datetime.now()), self.port)

               print 'query -> %s' % (self.query_from_MES)
               log.logging('query -> %s' % (self.query_from_MES), self.port)

               flag = self.query_from_MES[0:3]

               print 'flag -> %s' % (flag)
               log.logging('flag -> %s' % (flag), self.port)

               if flag == 'REQ':
                   answer = self.query_from_MES + work_with_DB.get_last_receiving_data(self.port)

                   print 'request from -> %s:%s' % (self.ip, self.port)
                   log.logging('request from -> %s:%s' % (self.ip, self.port), self.port)

                   print 'sent to MES -> %s...time =%s' % (answer, datetime.datetime.now())
                   log.logging('sent to MES -> %s...time =%s' % (answer, datetime.datetime.now()), self.port)

                   # send answer to client
                   self.conn.send(answer)
               else:
                   answer = work_with_DB.upload_data(self.query_from_MES[0:4000], self.port)
                   return_msg = self.query_from_MES[0:45] + answer

                   print 'send data from %s:%s' % (self.ip, self.port)
                   log.logging('send data from %s:%s...time =%s' % (self.ip, self.port, datetime.datetime.now()), self.port)

                   print 'sent to MES -> %s...time =%s' % (return_msg, datetime.datetime.now())
                   log.logging('sent to MES -> %s...time =%s' % (return_msg, datetime.datetime.now()), self.port)

                   self.conn.send(return_msg)

                   if answer[0:2] == conf._SEND_ERROR:
                       #print 'address =%s:%s...sleep 5 seconds...' % (self.ip, self.port)
                       #log.logging('address =%s:%s...sleep 5 seconds...' %     (self.ip, self.port))
                       #time.sleep(5)
                       #self.conn.settimeout(10)

                       print 'connection closed'
                       log.logging('connection closed', self.port)
                       self.conn.close()

                       #print 'socket closed'
                       #log.logging('socket closed')
                       #self.sock.close()
                       try:
                           self.run()
                           print 'restart server'
                           log.logging('restart server...', self.port)
                       except Exception as e:
                           # returns the name of the exception
                           print '__________EXCEPTION__________ %s :%s' %(type(e).__name__, e.message)
                          # returns the name of the exception
                           log.logging('__________EXCEPTION__________ %s :%s' % (type(e).__name__, e.message), self.port)

                           print 'START anew socket_server_9217'
                           log.logging('START anew socket_server_9217', self.port)
                           subprocess.Popen("socket_server_9217", shell=False)

           else:
               #print 'address =%s:%s...sleep 5 seconds...' % (self.ip, self.port)
               #log.logging('address =%s:%s...sleep 5 seconds...' % (self.ip, self.port))
               #time.sleep(5)
               #self.conn.settimeout(10)

               print 'connection closed'
               log.logging('connection closed', self.port)
               self.conn.close()

               #print 'socket closed'
               #log.logging('socket closed')
               #self.sock.close()

               try:
                   self.run()
                   print 'restart server'
                   log.logging('restart server...', self.port)
               except Exception as e:
                   # returns the name of the exception
                   print '__________EXCEPTION__________ %s :%s' % (type(e).__name__, e.message)
                   # returns the name of the exception
                   log.logging('__________EXCEPTION__________ %s :%s' % (type(e).__name__, e.message), self.port)

                   print 'START anew socket_server_9217'
                   log.logging('START anew socket_server_9217', self.port)
                   subprocess.Popen("socket_server_9217", shell=False)
   s = socket_server(conf._IP, conf._PORT_9217)
   s.run()`

Comment: Traceback, please?

Comment: Please give information about the error in detail

Comment: this error thrown like messageBox, from python.exe. this script works some hours and then raise an error

Comment: log-file haven't any information about exception

Comment: where I should add Traceback ?

Comment: I think you should edit your question and append it to the end

Comment: i separate log files - for each process personal log-file...and error didn't appear anymore. 24-hours without any crashes.

Comment: previous action doens't help.
as i found in google, too many recursion was an error reason. and i change my code

Comment: i import goto package `from goto import with_goto`

Comment: add annotations **@with_goto** to a class `def run(self)`

Comment: add `label.begin` before `while True`

Comment: add into else branch of `if not len(self.query_from_MES) == 0:` code `goto.begin`